# Matlab: latex command to output with 4 significant digits or with certain amount of decimals?

Tags: matlab, latex, symbolic-math

I want to generate a table for the results in Matlab. I use the symbolic box's `latex` command. How can I specify the amount of significant digits?

**Problem profile**

```
>> results

results =

    0.0025    0.0024    0.0024

>> latex(vpa(sym(results),4))       #THIS SHOULD PRINT with 4 decimals, how?

ans =

\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0.0025401858540021748922299593687057 & 0.0023686521873358401535369921475649 & 0.0023649304185866526495374273508787 \end{array}\right)

>> vpa(sym(results),4)

ans =

[ 0.00254, 0.002369, 0.002365]
```

Comment: Jonas provided [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21452748/164148) a method to manipulate the stdout, this is a solution but I am still happy to know whether the symbolic latex command has some builtin string-manipulation options. Hence left this question.

Answer (score 3):

I think that syntax for `vpa` sets the minimum number of significant figures.  Did you try setting the variable-precision accuracy?

```
d1 = digits(4); % records and sets accuracy
latex(vpa(sym(results)))
digits(d1); % restore previous accuracy
```

Comment: @hhh Is there any use of this answer? Did you try setting the variable-precision accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

THANK YOU!

I just created the following nifty function using this (to output transfer functions directly in latex format):

```
function tf2latex(tf)

[num,den]=tfdata(tf);
syms s
d1 = digits(4); % records and sets accuracy
latex(vpa(poly2sym(cell2mat(num),s)/poly2sym(cell2mat(den),s)))
digits(d1); 

end
```