# Matlab: regex conversion of long decimals in String to decimals with certain amount of digits after decimal point?

Tags: regex, string, matlab

I have the string as below. I would like to match all decimal numbers like `regexp(myS, '\.[0-9]+', 'match')` and then remove the excess digits after the decimal point. How can you do it in Matlab?

**Input String**

```
\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0.0000000000011 & 0.0023245508539986303730984218418598 & 0.0023219396894162969147146213799715 & 0.0023237598123344582745630759745836 \end{array}\right)
```

**String Outputs**

> **Easy Intended output string**
>
> ```
> \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0.000000 0.002324 & 0.002321 & 0.002323 \end{array}\right)
> ```
>
> **Harder Intended output string**
>
> ```
> \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1.100E-12 & 2.324E-3 & 2.321E-3 & 2.323E-3 \end{array}\right)
> ```

*P.s. I am considering here a solution candidate to this puzzle [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437777/matlab-latex-command-to-output-with-4-significant-digits-or-with-certain-amount) in trying to convert the results nicely from Matlab to LaTex.*

Comment: What is the condition for a digit being an excess digit?

Comment: For your harder output, shouldn't `0.000011E-7 0.002324E0` rather be `1.100000E-12 2.324000E-3`

Comment: @Dan fixed, good point.

Comment: @ceving I am happy with any easy solution 6 digits after decimal point (easy intended output) but ofc 4 significant numbers in the scientific form could be cool (harder intended output).

Comment: @hhh what exactly are you doing? Can't you just round off the numbers *before* converting them to LaTeX?

Comment: @Dan Round command? It converts only to the nearest integer. Yes basically round-offcing could work but I need to find a command for it which formats the string to certain precision -- the latex command only stdout the string so apparently have to regex format it, could not find stdout formatting options in latex command.

Comment: @hhh To round to `X` 6 decimal points: `round(X*1000000)/1000000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using `regexprep` with dynamic replacement expression:

```
regexprep(inputString,'([0-9\.E-]+)','${sprintf(''%8.6f'',str2double($0))}')
```

Here's the result for the first string (note: it's rounding "correctly", rather than chopping off digits)

```
\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0.000000 & 0.002325 & 0.002322 & 0.002324 \end{array}\right)
```

Here is the result for the second, harder, input string

```
\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0.000000 & 0.002324 & 0.002321 & 0.002323 \end{array}\right)
```

**EDIT**

Just noticed that it says "harder *output* string" - here's how to achieve that (though it does come with an always two-digit exponent). You can, of course, leave out the `E-` in the match expression if you don't want to match exponential notations.

```
out = regexprep(instr,'([0-9\.E-]+)','${sprintf(''%5.3e'',str2double($0))}')
ans =
\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1.100e-12 & 2.325e-03 & 2.322e-03 & 2.324e-03 \end{array}\right)
```